# How can I use VirtualDocumentRoot to serve the www subdomain with SSL enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am able to serve **http**://**www**.domain.com and http://domain.com. Also **https**://domain.com works fine too. But not **https**://**www**.domain.com for some reason this doesn't work. I even created a www.domain.com in my sites-availible folder and also enabled it. I reloaded the configuration and yet it still doesn't work.

I *have* a **wildcard certificate** so that is NOT the problem.

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
        ServerName *.domain.com:443
        ServerAlias www.domain.com
        VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you have a wildcard certificate for *.domain.com, then calls to https://domain.com should be giving you browser warnings of a certificate mismatch, since *.domain.com doesn't match domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

To have the same site listening on both HTTP and HTTPS you will need 2 virtual hosts, one for SSL and one for normal connections.

Remove :443 from your "ServerName" parameter.

I just created a config doing what you request here, in my test environment, and this is what I have in my working configuration file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>   
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin www@srv.fbh

    ServerName *.srv.fbh
    VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%0/ 

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/test/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/test/server.key   
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Also, you have a ServerAlias for www.domain.com - this is not necessary, as the wildcard *.domain.com will catch this.

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Part of problem is in the VirtualDocumentRoot line. %0 expands to the incoming domain name, which in your case means Apache would look for the site at `/www/www.domain.com`, which is not `/www/domain.com`. You could work around this by creating a symlink from one to the other, which is similar to what you did, or a better way would be to modify the VirtualDocumentroot to be `VirtualDocumentRoot /www/%-2.0.%-1`, which means to take the penultimate and ultimate parts of the incoming domainname, with a dot in between. Both domains would resolve to the path `/www/domain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_faq.html):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAlias *
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /path-to-keys/ca.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /path-to-keys/yours.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path-to-keys/bundle.crt

    RequestHeader set X_FORWARDED_PROTO 'https'
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Of course you need the proper files there, and remember to set `yours.key` to `chmod 400`. I did notice you got this part working already, just keeping the answer more complete. ;)